# Is there a specific word to describe tools used in engineering projects?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have found that:

- Doctors use "instruments".
- Cooks use "cookware" and "utensils".
- Construction workers use "construction materials", "tools" and "equipment".
- Sailors use "nautical tools" and "equipment".

All of these seem like alternatives in different professions to replace the word "tools"/ tools used to build or create something.

For engineers (specifically mechanical and electrical), is there a word for engineering tools that are used to build products?

Comment: What's a "nautical tool"?

Comment: What's wrong with _tools_? We are talking about the [tools of the trade](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Tools+of+the+Trade).

Comment: 'Gear' might be a good term to use. It implies tools but can also mean general equipment and also large haulage equipment etc.

Comment: A nautical tool is usually a reference to an instrument such as a sextant or a compass.

Comment: If you’re ok with construction workers using tools and equipment then mechanical and electrical engineers also use tools and equipment and sometimes machines and instruments too.

Comment: The last time I saw a _sextant_ was at the Naval Museum at Annapolis in 1974. We all use GPS  these days. In fact, it was kind of a  joke...

Answer (score 1):

As a trained engineer, I would say that engineering is such a wide field that you would need to be specific with regards to the type of engineering. As an aircraft engineer, I used aircraft engineering tools in general and then would name sub-divisions, such as aircraft electrical engineering tools, and so on. In your example, I would say: engineering structure tools.